# Google calendar sync issue with "Remember the milk" subscribed calendar

Tags: c++, google-calendar-api

We are using Google Calendar API v2  for syncing the Google calendar events to our desktop application. The application retrieves all calendar events and keeps it locally for  future reference.

I have sync issues with my "Remember the Milk" calendar, which I subscribed to using my Google calendar.

Here is my application flow:

1. Initially fetch calendar list by using the following HTTP request:
   https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/allcalendars/full
2. Fetch all events from calendar with the Calendar ID obtained in the previous request: http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/CalendarId/private/full?orderby=lastmodified&sortorder=descending&singleevents=true
3. Process each calendar one by one and save the calendar updated-min tag value as last calendar sync, in the next sync use this updated min value for retrieving updated events.

The documentation says it should give only updated events, but my  "Remember the Milk" calendar, always gives all events as updated events (on every 20 to 30 minutes).

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look  at your query string. You are missing the updated-min value. The query string should read.

```
http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/CalendarId/private/full?orderby=lastmodified&sortorder=descending&singleevents=true&updated-min=2005-08-09T10:57:00-
```

Comment: I am actually using the updated-min value query parameter in the query.